# Kubuntu 22.04 Thermal Monitor broken - cannot see CPU and SDD temperatures

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 22.04, temperature, plasma

I've just done the Kubuntu upgrade from 21.10 (impish) to 22.04 (jammy).

Now my Thermal Monitor plasma widget, which used to show CPU, GPU, SDD1 and SSD2 temperatures only shows the GPU temperature.

First thing I did was to check what lm-sensors reports, and running `sensors` I get this output:

```
$ sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:            N/A  

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +45.9 C  
Tccd1:        +45.2 C  
Tccd2:        +39.2 C  

nvme-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +39.9 C  (low  = -273.1 C, high = +84.8 C)
                       (crit = +89.8 C)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +45.9 C  (low  = -273.1 C, high = +81.8 C)
                       (crit = +84.8 C)
Sensor 1:     +45.9 C  (low  = -273.1 C, high = +65261.8 C)
Sensor 2:     +48.9 C  (low  = -273.1 C, high = +65261.8 C)
```

So the kernel and lm-sensors are aware of the temperatures (k10temp = CPU, nvme... = SSDs).

When I configure the Thermal Monitor widget though, there is no trace of a CPU thermal sensor. There are however the two SSD sensors listed. But when I check them, the widget still shows "OFF" for both (see screenshot below).

Any ideas what I could do to get my thermal monitoring back into a working state?

[image: Thermal Monitor - CPU sensor missing, SSD sensors not working]

Comment: Looks like the issue is only with the Thermal Monitor widget. Using the System Monitor widget I'm able to access both CPU and SSD temperature sensors just fine. So for now I've switched to a graph in my side panel that contains a bunch of other System Monitor widgets (CPU load, network upload/download, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Download ksysguardd_5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/ksysguard/ksysguardd_5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

`sudo dpkg -i ksysguardd_5.18.4.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

relogin, it should work

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in `ksystemstats`, where `coretemp`, `k10temp` and `amdgpu` are blacklisted.

The bug hasn't been corrected yet (see **edit**), but it's possible to temporarily patch it yourself. The process is described here:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438318#c37

Just check in `System settings` | `About this System` which Plasma version you're on to download the correct source code.

---

**edit** 2022-08-08

According to @BoeroBoy comment the bug has been corrected.

Comment: Update - this fix is finally released and the regression addressed.  Thanks to the devs for sorting it!
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438318#c37

Comment: It's not fixed, hence https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=452763